# Problem with documents printed with HP LaserJet 2200

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 2200 PCL5. Recently, when I print the output is very messy. It correctly prints what I want, but it is almost as though a faded version of the content is also printed after. For example if the document has written:

Hello World

Then it will be printed correctly, but a faded hello world would be written further down.

What could be the problem? I've tried changing the toner cartridge.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a problem with the imaging drum or the transfer roller. Comparing the echo separation with the circumferences should identify the cause.

From reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printer#Cleaning) it may be that the discharge lamp (or equivalent) needs replacing. I'd check the manual to see if this sort of repair is possible. In modern printers it may be part of the cartridge, try a new cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

This printer seems to be about 10 years old, if my googling wasn't mistaken.

It is highly unlikely that it can be repaired or that you could find any spare parts (or new drivers), unless you have another one that can be cannibalized for it.

It is probably not worth the investment to fix, especially as new printers are now quite cheap.
It might be time for a new printer.

Answer (score 0):

I love these printers and yes it can be repaired.  If you change the toner cartridge and still get the same problem it is the fuser.  You can also test it by printing, stopping the job before the paper hits the fuser.  If there are no ghosts, it's the fuser.

We have had print driver issues (due to the age of the printer) on these but only in a Mac networked environment. You can buy "recharged" cartridges for these machines and save yourself a ton of printing costs.